# Columnstore index how many columns

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, columnstore, covering-index

I have a table with 7 columns. The user could want any of these columns for the query.  So I am going to create a columnstore index for all 7 columns.  Is this a sound plan?  Or is there some problem with creating for all columns?

Comment: What kind of queries run against that table  ?

Comment: Mostly aggregate queries, there will be some predicates too but it will be like month over month type of queries or segment queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just used all columns.   This is actually a silly question because of course u should put all columns if they are being used.